# Google Analytics API Start-date and End-date

Tags: api, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, dashboard

I am trying to get some data from my Google Analytics account through the Google API.

What I need to do is to get the data so far for this month. Do some of you know what should be added in the start-date?

I am not being able to figure this out as the only thing I can find is that I can add, today, yesterday and other numbers but dont know how to add "this month".

What I want to do is that, when a new month starts it automatically goes back to zero and starts again for the new months. Please help.

Comment: which language are you using you should be able to calculate that yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're asking is not possible via the API directly. You're going to have to write some code to figure out what the start of the month is before sending the API request.